# django rest framework dynamic "manual" @detail_route declarations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.6

I have some highly repetitive code in my REST declarations, so I decided to inject `@detail_route` methods instead of re-declaring them over and over.

However, between version 3.7.7 of drf and version 3.8.2, something (well, the URL generation functions, that's what) changed and these dynamically added detail routes are no longer registered in the router / rendered into URLs.

My code:

```
class SiteTreeViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
.....

def generic_model_rest(model_, field, serfield):

    @detail_route()
    def _f(self, request, pk=None):
        itm = SiteTree.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
        serializer = globals()['Settings' + serfield + 'Serializer']
        if serfield in ('WWW', 'Oth',):
            data = serializer(getattr(itm, 'get_sett_' + serfield.lower())(), many=True)
        else:
            data = serializer(getattr(itm, 'get_sett_' + serfield.lower())())
        return Response(data.data)

setattr(SiteTreeViewSet, 'settings_%s' % serfield.lower(), _f)



generic_model_rest(SettingsApartment, 'apartment', 'Apt')
generic_model_rest(SettingsSwitch, 'switch', 'Swt')
generic_model_rest(SettingsWeblinks, 'weblinks', 'WWW')
generic_model_rest(SettingsWeblinks, 'weblinks1', 'WW1')
generic_model_rest(SettingsOther, 'other', 'Oth')

router.register(r'rest/sitetree', SiteTreeViewSet, 'SiteTree')
```

Do I have any other options for "manually" inserting detail routes?

Answer (score 2):

The newer version DRF has no detail_route and list_route decorators
you can try following

```
from rest_framework.decorators import action
...
...
...


@action(detail=True)
def _f(self, request, pk=None):
    ......
```

check in here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Answer (score 0):

@detail_route and @list_route are now deprecated in favor of action routes. recommend downgrading or using @action routes.

see patch 3.8.0 for details
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/release-notes/

Comment: Deprecated they migt be, but I just changed everything to `@action` with same results: it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Debugged the heck out of it: URL composition has been completely revamped (read: changed) in the new version. Now url will be composed from function name directly, not from function as it is inserted into the target ViewSet class.

Ultimately, I had to change the following two things:

```
@action(detail=True, url_path='settings_%s' % serfield.lower())
def _f(self, request, pk=None):
    .....

_f.__name__ = 'settings_%s' % serfield.lower()
```

I don't think change to @action was necessary, but I'm too lazy to check.

I had to add `url_path` parameter to the decorator itself and then also set the `__name__` attribute of the function. The latter is necessary because drf uses that for uniqueness in internal dictionaries while building routes. The former is now auto-generated during decoration, not during evaluation / routing as before.